# Looking references for a multi-tenant footprint architecture to deploy on Azure

Tags: azure, saas, multi-tenant

I´m interested to capture links, references and comments about multi-tenant architectures to deploy in the modality SaaS (Software as a Service) on the Windows Azure Platform.

Comment: Have you checked Microsoft Azure case studies http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/evidence/
 You may find something of your interest

Answer (score 0):

One link for you is the Fabrikam shipping sample from microsoft - https://fabrikamshipping.cloudapp.net/

Source code - http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/fshipsaassource

Blog posts - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2010/10/07/new-online-demo-introducing-fabrikamshipping-saas.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at our [sample and book](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966499.aspx). It is similar to Fabrikam but has the content that goes along with the code that talks about all the trade offs. We will be updating our code/content in the next month to work with the new features of Windows Azure (ACS & Caching).

You can get the [book on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735656061).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brand new multi-tenant sample application, [Cloud Ninja](http://cloudninja.codeplex.com/), that demonstrates several facets of a multi-tenant application in Windows Azure. There's also a related blog [here](http://www.fullscale180.com/Blog/).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might need for your multi-tenant architecture is to have multiple SSL certificates (one for each tenant's custom domain) for a single HTTPS binding.

I'm a Microsoft Technical Evangelist and I have posted a detailed explanation and a sample "plug & play" source-code on how to do it with Azure Cloud Services with SNI at:
http://www.vic.ms/microsoft/windows-azure/multiples-ssl-certificates-on-windows-azure-cloud-services/

Comment: Hi, I would like to know if it is possible to use single SSL certificate (*.example.com) for multiple custom domains (www.example.com and www.anotherexample.com) for Azure web app service.

Thank You!